# Scrub lead against National DNC

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, voicemail

Scrub lead against National DNC
What does this mean?
I have Ringless VoiceMail API 
and some of settings is this

> " scrub_nat_dnc': true, //# Scrub lead against National DNC "

Should I turn this to true?

Comment: have you tried [searching the internet](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Scrub+lead+against+National+DNC&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_nLkWKupF6vr8AfYsozgCg) - as to "should I turn this to true" - I would recommend you do what is best for you to do

Comment: I dont know what this means thats why Im asking here

Comment: it's not a programming question - do you know what the National DNC is?

Answer (score 0):

The DNC is the do not call list.

In the Unites States, by law, you have to 'scrub' the phone numbers you are dialling against a list of people and businesses who have opted out of receiving calls. They pay a fee to list themselves in either the national don't call list or the state don't call list (USA) (there are two). A violation of the law results in a $500 penalty per call and a class action suit does not have to be used to sue. You can set your software as you like but if you're list isn't scrubbed it won't change anything.